# How to create an API key which is tenant and application specific?

Tags: java, api, fusionauth

I am using java api to create tenants and applications. But I couldn’t find any javadocs which will let me create API key for a newly created tenant from java directly. Can you point me to java doc or an example?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is not an API to create API keys. The only way to create an API key is using [Kickstart](https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/installation-guide/kickstart) or the FusionAuth Admin UI ([Settings > API Keys](https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/apis/authentication)).

You can then optionally create an API key with access only to the Application API by limiting the allowed endpoints to `/api/application`.

Comment: Can you enhance java api to have this functionality? We create frequent tenants and application per tenant. And need to create api  key specific to this tenant/application. Since this entire creation process is managed by using fusionauth java client it makes sense to also create api key programmatically. Thanks!

Comment: Good feedback. Can you open a GitHub feature request in the fusionauth-issues project? We'll track the request there. Thanks!